# Spark Structured Streaming - Force microbatch execution even without input rows

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We have a Spark Structured Streaming query that counts the number of input rows received on the last hour, updating every minute, performing the aggrupation with a temporal window (`windowDuration="1 hour"`, `slideDuration="1 minute"`). The query is configured to use a processingTime trigger, with a duration of 30 secods `trigger(processingTime="30 seconds")`. The `outputMode` of the query is `append`.

This query produces results as long as new rows are received, which is consistent with the behaviour that the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers) indicates for fixed interval micro-batches:

> If no new data is available, then no micro-batch will be kicked off.

However, we would like the query to produce results even when there are NO input rows: our use case is related to monitorization, and we would like to trigger alerts when there are no input messages in the monitorized system for a period of time.

For example, for the following input:

| event_time | event_id |
| --- | --- |
| 00:02 | 1 |
| 00:05 | 2 |
| 01:00 | 3 |
| 03:00 | 4 |

At processingTime=01:01, we could suppose that the following output row would be produced:

| window.start | window.end | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 01:00 | 3 |

However, from this point, there are no input rows until 03:00, and therefore, no microbatch will be executed until this time, missing the opportunity to produce output rows such as:

| window.start | window.end | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01:01 | 02:01 | 0 |

Which would otherwise produce a monitoring alert in our system.

**Is there any workaround for this behaviour, allowing executions of empty microbatches when there are no input rows?**

Comment: No is also an answer

Comment: Did u resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ask for things not provided in the software as such, and there are no work arounds. There was even a time, that may still exist, in which the last set of microbatch data is not processed.